# Is this a correct understanding of transactions?

Tags: postgresql, transaction

I have just noticed that one of my TRUNCATE queries takes 16 seconds to complete. I always assumed that TRUNCATE queries were basically-instant.

I currently do this:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE bigtable RESTART IDENTITY;
INSERT INTO bigtable (col) VALUES ($1); -- This one is run countless times.
```

Question 1: Since it takes 16 seconds for the TRUNCATE to do its thing, does that mean that for 16 seconds, my applications might be querying the bigtable and get nothing returned?

Question 2: If I do the following, will my applications continue to get the old values until the entire new dataset has been loaded in? Or will something else happen?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
TRUNCATE TABLE bigtable RESTART IDENTITY;
INSERT INTO bigtable (col) VALUES ($1); -- This one is run countless times.
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

As I understand it, the BEGIN ... COMMIT "block" will basically not "go live" until the COMMIT, at which point both the TRUNCATE and all the INSERTS have taken place, so at that moment, the applications will get the new data, but until then, they will get the old data rather than NO or PARTIAL data?

Correct?

Answer (score 3):

`TRUNCATE` is indeed very fast, but it has to take an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table.

For this, the query has to wait until all concurrent transactions that use the table (even if only for a `SELECT`!) are done. Only then can it take the lock and execute the actual truncation.

To make it faster, see that concurrent transactions are short. 16 seconds is an awfully long time for a database transaction.

To your questions:

1. All the transactions that started before the `TRUNCATE` (and that block it) will see the complete, untruncated table.

   All transactions that start after the `TRUNCATE` will be blocked until the `TRUNCATE`'s transaction is done, even if they only `SELECT` from the table.
2. If you `TRUNCATE` and `INSERT` in the same transaction, the `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock is held until the whole transaction is done.

   So it will be like in the previous case, but the transactions that started later will see the table filled immediately.

Comment: As you mentioned in 2, is there any way we can run two different transaction in a  function?

Comment: No, that is impossible. A function always runs as part of a single transaction.

Comment: I have the same scenario mentioned above and records about 500k records for a run. Is there any best way to solve the issue? Can we use SP for that? I think we can use multiple transactions in SP?

Comment: What's the problem with doing it in a single transaction?

Answer (score 1):

There are [different isolation levels you can select in Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html), but I'll assume the default of "READ COMMITTED". There are levels that provide more guarantees in Postgres, but you can't ask for less isolation (READ UNCOMMITTED is not supported by Postgres).

The big guarantee you get in this isolation level is that your transactions will never see uncommitted data from other transactions. So for example, if you have a transaction that inserts 1000 rows into a table, any other transaction will either see none of these rows or all of them, it will never see only half of them inserted. Within a single transaction though, the changes are always directly visible to that transaction alone.

Unfortunately, [TRUNCATE is an exception and doesn't entirely behave like other SQL commands in this regard](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc-caveats.html). The truncation can be visible to other transactions even while the transaction with the TRUNCATE command is still running. As far as I understand, this would still not make something like a half-truncated table visible, but I'm not 100% sure how to read the documentation there.

Comment: I think the MVCC inconsistencies mentioned for `TRUNCATE` can only manifest at an isolation of `REPEATABLE READ` or higher.